# operator system of equations

Tags: matrix-equations

What is the solution of the following matrix equation?

$(F_2^-+F_3^-+F_4^-)Q_1=0\\
(F_2^++F_3^-+F_4^-)Q_2=0\\
(F_3^++F_4^-)Q_3=0\\
(F_4^+)Q_4=0\\
Q_1+Q_2+Q_3+Q_4=I$

where $Q_i$s are positive definite matrixes and $F_i^+$ and $F_i^-$ means the positive and negative subspaces of the matrix $F_i$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.